# android ImageView setContentDescription with ListAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a news list. I use this;

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, getXmlData(URL,KEY_ITEM,KEY_COLUMN),
            R.layout.news_list,
            new String[] { KEY_COLUMN[1],KEY_COLUMN[0] }, new int[] {
        R.id.name,R.id.list_image});
```

KEY_COLUMN[1] is caption.
KEY_COLUMN[0] is id value. It must be hidden.

My problem is R.id.list_image.
I can set KEY_COLUMN[0] to src of R.id.list_image. But i want to set KEY_COLUMN[0] to contentDescription of R.id.list_image.
Can you help? I don't use lazyadaptor etc.

EDİT:
i have new problem. if i need 2 data for imageview, how can i use?

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, getXmlData(URL,KEY_ITEM,KEY_COLUMN),
            R.layout.news_list,
            new String[] { KEY_COLUMN[1],KEY_COLUMN[0],KEY_COLUMN[2] }, new int[] {
        R.id.name,R.id.list_image,R.id.list_image});
```

KEY_COLUMN[0] set to setContentDescription of R.id.list_image
KEY_COLUMN[2] set to src of R.id.list_image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use custom binder to do this. It can be accomplished with adding something like this in the next line:

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                String textRepresentation) {
            // Log.v(TAG, "Binding view: " + view);

            if (view.getId() == R.id.list_image) {
                ((ImageView) view).setContentDescription((CharSequence)) data);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: if i need 2 data for imageview, how can i use?
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, getXmlData(URL,KEY_ITEM,KEY_COLUMN),
            R.layout.news_list,
            new String[] { KEY_COLUMN[1],KEY_COLUMN[0],KEY_COLUMN[2] }, new int[] {
        R.id.name,R.id.list_image,R.id.list_image});

KEY_COLUMN[0] set to setContentDescription of R.id.list_image
KEY_COLUMN[2] set to src of R.id.list_image